# Quick question: Implementation of a slidshow of sections?

Tags: html, css

Quick question here. I am building a website (sketch linked) and would like for the site to be a single page that has a slideshow of sections. By this I mean that when the user clicks on a menu bar link (green), rather than them being taken to a new page, the current information (red box) is replaced by a new section. Effectively like a slidshow of sections within a page.

[image]

Currently I would be looking to implement this functionality by controling the css `visibility` property via JS that would be triggered by clicking on a link.

Any other ideas or better ways of doing this? I have attempted to find some implementations of this on other websites but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, using javascript and CSS you can achieve this. First, render all the contents associated to the menu one below the other, then set display: none property on the container div (red border). when clicking on the menu button set display: block property on the appropriate div.

Comment: If you had tried anything share your code here so that I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a small snippet. In this snippet, the content is **toggled** when the menu items are clicked.
I am only using `CSS` and `JS` to achieve this

```js
function clicked(cls) {
  const c = document.body.querySelector('.container');
  Array.from(c.children).forEach((item)=> item.classList.remove('visible'));
  var x = document.querySelector(`.${cls}`);
  x.classList.add('visible')
}
```

```css
.section1, .section2, .section3 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: wheat;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div  onclick="clicked('section1')">section 1</div>
  <div  onclick="clicked('section2')">section 2</div>
  <div  onclick="clicked('section3')">section 3</div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
  <div class="section1 visible">
  This is First section.
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
  This is Second section.
  </div>
  <div class="section3">
  This is Third section.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much more concise JS Script than what I came up with. Thanks!